# SharedPreferences crash

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Добрый день.

> Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Ошибка на строке с присвоением.
Если он ещё не создан, то есть дефаулт, почему `NullPointerException`?

```
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
boolean ifWasSet;

public void makeList() {
    ifWasSet = settings.getBoolean("comp", false);
    if (ifWasSet == true) {
        System.out.println("Ne dobavlyaem");
    } else {
        persons.add(student1);
        persons.add(student2);
        persons.add(student3);
        persons.add(student4);
        settings =
            getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("comp", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас переменная settings используется до `if`, а присваиваете значение вы ей только в блоке `else`. так должно быть?

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня есть данные, которые нужно добавить только один раз. Сначала всё должно быть FALSE, а потом уже после одного добавления всегда TRUE.

Answer (score 3):

вы пытаетесь использовать `settings` до того, как запишете в него что-либо. `ifWasSet = settings.getBoolean("comp",false);` Сначала запишите что-нибудь в `settings`, а потом уже вызывайте у него методы.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не могу присвоить ему значение сначала, так как после пересоздания активити, значение измениться с TRUE на FALSE.

Comment: @T.Tester, а придется. Прежде, чем сказать, "машина, едь!" нужно купить машину. Если вы пустому месту скажете "едь", то ничего хорошего не произойдет.